# How do I configure log4j to send log events to java.util.logging using JULAppender?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, java.util.logging

I am familiar with the java.util.logging (JUL) framework, I use it extensively.   Recently, I started using a library that does its logging through log4j.    When I start my application I now get the following printed on the console:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.example.thirdparty.Library).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

It appears that log4j has a solution for this: [JULAppender](http://people.apache.org/~psmith/logging.apache.org/sandbox/jul-log4j-bridge/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/jul/JULAppender.html) which will send everything logged with log4j to the logging framework that I use.

I can't find any examples that show me how to configure log4j to use this appender.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard way of configuring log4j is to create *log4j.xml* in the root of the classpath.  Here are contents of that file configured for JULAppender:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
    <appender name="jul" class="org.apache.log4j.JulAppender"> 
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"> 
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p %c - %m%n "/> 
        </layout> 
    </appender> 
    <root> 
        <priority value="all" /> 
        <appender-ref ref="jul" /> 
    </root>  
</log4j:configuration>
```

Comment: FYI `org.apache.log4j.JulAppender` is for the [now ancient Log4j v1](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/); the other answers here (notably re. [LOG4J2-3282](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-3282)) are applicable for [Log4j v2.x](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/).

Answer (score 1):

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-3282 proposes the creation of a (TBD) `log4j-to-jul` Bridge.

Comment: And that issue is now fixed with fix version 2.17.2. This is great news!

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of [JULAppender](http://people.apache.org/%7Epsmith/logging.apache.org/sandbox/jul-log4j-bridge/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/jul/JULAppender.html) (which, btw, is available for download [here](http://people.apache.org/%7Epsmith/logging.apache.org/repo/org/apache/logging/apache-jul-log4j-bridge/)), is very old now (from 2008), and targets JDK 1.4 and log4j version 1.2.15.

If you work with log4j version 2.0 (and above), an easy solution would be to have all messages logged with log4j's [SLF4J appender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/log4j-to-slf4j/index.html), which, in turn, is set to use `java.util.logging` as its underlying implementation.

If you use maven simply include the following in your `<dependencies>` paragraph:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.7</version>
</dependency>
```

If you don't use maven in your project, just download (from maven website) and include the following 3 jars in your CLASSPATH to get the same effect (in addition to `log4j-api-2.0.jar`):

- `log4j-to-slf4j-2.0.jar`
- `1slf4j-jdk14-1.7.7.jar`
- `slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar`

Comment: Does this really require JDK 14? What about people forced to use JDK 8?

Comment: no, it's an old an unfortunate label, where JDK14 actually means Jdk1.4, which is much older than JDK8 you're targeting

Comment: btw, your `SLF4J appender` link is dead.