# How to setup 4 Maven projects with slf4j and different logging utilities?

Tags: java, maven, log4j, slf4j

So I have 4 Maven projects, let's call them A, B, C and D. Project A depends on project B depends on project C and project A depends on project D too.

D
^
|
A -> B -> C

Project A and B use `slf4j`
Project C uses `java.util.logging`
Project D uses `log4j`

Now I do not really know how to set up it's logging dependencies to get it working.

What I have is:
Project D depends on `log4j` and nothing else.
Project C depends on nothing because it just uses java's logging utility.
Project B depends on `slf4j-api` as well as `jul-to-slf4j` to also log what C logs
Project A depends on `slf4j-api`, `slf4j-log4j12` and `log4j`

Project A is the main program which I want to run. It has a log4j.properties file set up for logging to console.

```
# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1} - %m%n

# Direct all messages there
log4j.rootLogger = INFO, stdout
```

The problem now is, that when I start the program all slf4j logs will get ignored. I tried to log something using a log4j-Logger in Project A and that gets logged.

Project A's dependency tree:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:tree (default-cli) @ devopstool ---
[INFO] PROJECT A
[INFO] +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.antlr:antlr-runtime:jar:3.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.antlr:stringtemplate:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] +- org.tmatesoft.svnkit:svnkit:jar:1.8.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.jcraft:jsch.agentproxy.svnkit-trilead-ssh2:jar:0.0.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.jcraft:jsch.agentproxy.core:jar:0.0.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.java.dev.jna:jna-platform:jar:4.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.java.dev.jna:jna:jar:4.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.trilead:trilead-ssh2:jar:1.0.0-build217:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.jcraft:jsch.agentproxy.connector-factory:jar:0.0.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.jcraft:jsch.agentproxy.usocket-jna:jar:0.0.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- net.java.dev.jna:platform:jar:3.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.jcraft:jsch.agentproxy.usocket-nc:jar:0.0.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.jcraft:jsch.agentproxy.sshagent:jar:0.0.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.jcraft:jsch.agentproxy.pageant:jar:0.0.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- de.regnis.q.sequence:sequence-library:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.tmatesoft.sqljet:sqljet:jar:1.1.10:compile
[INFO] +- org.tmatesoft.svnkit:svnkit-cli:jar:1.8.9:compile
[INFO] +- org.tmatesoft.svnkit:svnkit-javahl16:jar:1.8.9:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.subversion:svn-javahl-api:jar:1.8.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.jgoodies:forms:jar:1.2.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.jsoup:jsoup:jar:1.8.2:compile
[INFO] +- PROJECT D
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:18.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.jcraft:jsch:jar:0.1.52:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jetbrains:annotations:jar:13.0:compile
[INFO] +- PROJECT B
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.chemistry.opencmis:chemistry-opencmis-client-impl:jar:0.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.chemistry.opencmis:chemistry-opencmis-client-api:jar:0.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.chemistry.opencmis:chemistry-opencmis-commons-api:jar:0.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.chemistry.opencmis:chemistry-opencmis-commons-impl:jar:0.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:jar:4.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0-2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-rt:jar:2.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- javax.xml.ws:jaxws-api:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- com.sun.xml.stream.buffer:streambuffer:jar:0.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal:resolver:jar:20050927:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.jvnet:mimepull:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.chemistry.opencmis:chemistry-opencmis-client-bindings:jar:0.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.felix:org.osgi.core:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.alfresco.cmis.client:alfresco-opencmis-extension:jar:0.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- PROJECT C
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.2.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:jar:2.2.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:jar:2.16:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.sun.xml.fastinfoset:FastInfoset:jar:1.2.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- javax.xml.bind:jsr173_api:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj:saaj-impl:jar:1.3.23:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- javax.xml.soap:javax.xml.soap-api:jar:1.3.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.jvnet.mimepull:mimepull:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.jvnet.staxex:stax-ex:jar:1.7.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.7:compile
[INFO] +- com.miglayout:miglayout-swing:jar:5.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.miglayout:miglayout-core:jar:5.0:compile
[INFO] \- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.7:compile
```

Comment: Are you using logger.info? Not debug or trace? Because that's your default logger level.

Comment: yes, I want all info logs to be shown

Comment: Could you post `mvn dependency:tree` output of your A project somewhere? (that's the one that doesn't work, right?

Comment: Can you check your stderr output for any message like "SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings."?

Comment: My problem really is that slf4j doesn't output anything. The only logs I can see, are the ones I call directly via the log4j-Logger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your dependency tree you have multiple SLF4J bindings.

```
[INFO] |  |     |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-nop:jar:1.5.3:runtime
[INFO] |  |     |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:jar:1.5.6:runtime
[INFO] \- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.7:compile
```

You would find message similar to this on standard error output if that is the case (beware that this might be different from standard output and you are not actually seeing this - this depends on how you execute your app).

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/frantisek/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-nop/1.7.12/slf4j-nop-1.7.12.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/frantisek/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.3/logback-classic-1.1.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.helpers.NOPLoggerFactory]
```

Actually the whole maven-assembly-plugin dependency doesn't seem right, unless you are developing a maven plugin.

```
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:jar:2.5.3:compile
```

To solve this either exclude `slf4j-nop` and `slf4j-jdk14` or remove whole dependency.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I fixed the maven-assembly-plugin dependency. Which should fix multiple bindings issue. Updated the dependency tree. Edit: Thanks again that fixed everything! SLF4J logging works now as expected.

Answer (score 1):

It's a really good idea to get your whole project logging into ONE logging system, in your case that would probably be log4j. This streamlines everything and allows you to use one config file, etc. instead of having multiple configurations, etc.

Slf4j is a logging facade, as you probably know, so you can bind it to log4j without much trouble. A slightly bigger problem (but not unsolvable) will be project C. Let's start with the easier stuff:

To bridge slf4j to log4j you only have to include a dependency to the SLF4J LOG4J 12 Binding:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.12</version>
</dependency>
```

This will allow slf4j to use log4j, which means your log4j.xml file (or similar) will be used, etc.

Hint (Edited in, as Niklas P mentioned it in a comment): You CAN of course also log to JUL instead of log4j from SLF4j, no problem there, but it's slightly trickier to route the log4j (from project D) to JUL (and requires one more config file), so I wouldn't go that way. But that is also a question of personal preference (I prefer log4j(2)). If you want to do that, you can add the jdk14 binding for Slf4j instead and try routing your log4j stuff from project D to JUL, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23839530/how-do-i-configure-log4j-to-send-log-events-to-java-util-logging-using-julappend) for that.

You perhaps might get warnings that there are other bindings (in which case slf4j will use one pretty much randomly). You must exclude the other ones then by looking at the "effective pom" (Eclipse Maven has a tab for that, for example) and then exclude these bindings from the dependencies. For example, in one of my project, I have something like this...

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.zkoss.zk</groupId>
        <artifactId>zkspring-core</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <!-- Exclude logback binding for slf4j -->
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    <dependency>
```

You should always only have exactly ONE binding on your classpath. It's a really bad practice to include a binding in your library's dependencies, because that's something the application should decide. See the "Multiple Bindings" section of http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html

This will take care of your slf4j/log4j binding problem. Your next problem is project C, which uses JUL (java.util.logging).

You can bridge that to Log4j by using the adapter:

> To use the JDK Logging Adapter, you must set the system property
>   java.util.logging.manager to org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager
>
> This must be done either through the command line (i.e., using the
>   -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager argument) or by using System.setProperty() before any calls are made
>   to LogManager or Logger.
>   see https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/log4j-jul/index.html

And as a personal note: As apache has announced the [end of life](http://Apache%E2%84%A2%20Logging%20Services%E2%84%A2%20Project%20Announces%20Log4j%E2%84%A2%201%20End-Of-Life;%20Recommends%20Upgrade%20to%20Log4j%202) for log4j 1.2, I suggest thinking about switching to log4j2.

Comment: What about using a bridge from slf4j to JUL the same way as from slf4j to log4j? The bridge would be: **slf4j-jdk14-1.7.12.jar**

Comment: Probably personaly preference, but I would always use log4j instead of jul. Anyway, it's of course possible to log slf4j to JUL - but iirc it's not that easy to route log4j stuff to JUL and requires a little bit more work. And as he's already using log4j in project D, I would suggest keeping that for the whole thing. But if you want to go that way (routing log4j to jul) there's an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23839530/how-do-i-configure-log4j-to-send-log-events-to-java-util-logging-using-julappend

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Wouldnt it be multiple bindings if i used slf4j-jdk14 and slf4j-log4j12 at the same time?

Comment: Yes, that would indeed be multiple bindings and you should avoid that (since the result is pretty random). The JDK14 binding would be used INSTEAD of log4j and you would have to exclude any log4j binding that crept in as a dependency in your pom.xml via exclusion.