# use both log4j and java.util.logging together

Tags: logging, log4j, java.util.logging

We are using log4j for logging but Application also depend on several third parties which use java.util.logging.
It is pretty straight forward to change format in logging.properties to make it same like other logs but how do I make sure that these third parties write in same file as main application is doing.

I fear that if I use same file in logging.properties, log4j and logging.properties might cause perf and correctness issues. Otherwise I will need to create different file for those which is not desirable in my case.  Is there any clean way

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to have both frameworks open the same target file as JUL wants exclusive ownership the target log file.

You need a [logging bridge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23839530/how-do-i-configure-log4j-to-send-log-events-to-java-util-logging-using-julappend) which converts log records from JUL and publishes them to Log4J.

One example is the [Log4j JDK Logging Adapter](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/log4j-jul/index.html):

> The JDK Logging Adapter is a custom implementation of java.util.logging.LogManager that uses Log4j. This adapter can be used with either the Log4j API or Log4j Core. When used with the API, there are a couple features of JUL that aren’t supported. However, this does allow any other Log4j Provider besides the Core provider to be used with JUL.
>
> To use the JDK Logging Adapter, you must set the system property java.util.logging.manager to org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager

Another popular example is [jul-to-slf4j bridge](https://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html#jul-to-slf4j)

> The jul-to-slf4j.jar artifact includes a java.util.logging (jul) handler, namely SLF4JBridgeHandler, which routes all incoming jul records to the SLF4j API.

Comment: looks like its time I upgrade to log4j2